# Multiplicity is not allowed - 2FK in Same master table - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
Class Menu {
public Int64 ID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentMenu")]
public Int64? ParentID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CombinedMenu")]
public Int64? CombinedMenuID { get; set; }

public virtual Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
public virtual Menu CombinedMenu { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to add a second key in the table. But showing multiplicity error.
How can i solve this?

Error Message when adding migration : Menu_ParentMenu_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Menu_ParentMenu_Target' in relationship 'Menu_ParentMenu'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: @Pac0 Question updated. Please check

Comment: @Pac0 ParentMenu is the only FK exist in the table. Today i added new key CombineMenuID. Just added CombineMenuID in entity class & tried to add migration by using entity command " add-migration" in package manager console.

Comment: Actually "ID" is PK.